# Is it faster to access a Dictionary stored in Session, or multiple objects stored in Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, dictionary

I have about 20 different variables stored in my Session variable for an ASP.NET application. On each page, I have to access around 5-7 of those variables. My question is would it be faster for me to store all my session variables in a Dictionary and retrieve this Dictionary on my page?  Or is it faster to retrieve all 7 of the variables from Session? Which of these two scenarios would be faster?

```
//Perform this for 7 variables
if(Session["var1"] != null)
    var1 = Session["var1"]
```

Or this:

```
if(Session["dict"] != null)
    dict = Session["dict"]

//Perform this for 7 variables
if(dict.TryGetValue(name, out var1))
    //perform action
```

Comment: Try both, measure your performance and you will know. My guess, there shouldn't be any difference, even if there is, it should be negligible.

Comment: You've asked us a question that only you can answer. We don't have your web app, we don't know how your Session state provider is implemented.

Comment: The 'access' time would be negligible.  Your code comments aptly point out that maintainability is the real bonus with using a dict.

Comment: Why are you using a Session variable to store this information?

Comment: Session is stored as a hasmap based on the string key. It would suprise me if you get can speed benefit on the total page cycle. Please share your results with us. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Okay, I see, so in other words, either way you are accessing the Session for the page. Whether you hit it one time or seven is a minimal difference?